# No being able to delete a filestore instance on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm having a  problem with my cloud.google.com account. I'm trying to delete my filestore instance but it's keep loading and i can't do anything anymore.
When i go to the activities it shows me the following:

> google cloud filestore v1 CloudFilestoreManager DeleteInstance uitgevoerd op project- but it is still loading.

Is there any we to solve this without having a lot of Cloud knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

I would sugest to try using the gcloud sdk :

1.check to see if instance was deleted

```
    gcloud filestore instances list
    gcloud filestore instances describe your-instance --zone your-instance-zone
```

2.delete the instance

```
gcloud filestore instances delete [INSTANCE_ID] \
 --project=[PROJECT_ID] \
 --zone=[ZONE]
```

where:

> [INSTANCE_ID] is the identifier of the Filestore instance.
>
> [PROJECT_ID] is the ID of the GCP project that contains the Filestore
>   instance. You can skip this flag if you have set the gcloud default
>   project and want to use that.
>
> [ZONE] is the GCP zone in which the Filestore instance resides.
>
> Run the gcloud filestore zones list command to get a list of supported
>   zones. You can skip this flag if you have set the gcloud default zone
>   by running the gcloud config set filestore/zone command.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer unfortunately this is not working. I. tried this bit i gives me an error:

peration https://file.googleapis.com/v1p1alpha1/projects/monaerk-nld/locations/us-central1-a/operations/operation-1585837948052-5a24fab90a5f1-cd7df770-703cb7ef has not finished in 1800 seconds. The operations may still be underway remotely and may still succeed; use gcloud list and describe commands or https://console.developers.google.com/ to check resource state.

Which is weird because i am the only one with access to filestore.

Comment: how long have you waited?